# Spring RequestMapping to read encoded &amp

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get a RequestMapping to pick up the following url pathname.

```
action?param1=6&amp;param2=b&amp;param3=true&amp;param4=50652&amp;param5=2
```

I'm able to get the path below to work. However when converting & to  '& amp;' I am unable to read any parameters.

```
action?param1=6&param2=b&param3=true&param4=50652&param5=2
```

Method for action

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/action", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doAction(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
        throws Exception {
log.info(httpRequest.getParameter("param1"));
}
```

FYI
I want to steer clear of any string manipulations

Comment: In your example I see your URL is "action?..." Shouldn't that actually be ".../promoRate?param1=6&param2=b..."

Comment: What is your expected value for `param1`? In the version using `&amp;`, `param1` should get the value `6`, but the other params are named, e.g. `amp;param2`...

Comment: The parameter comes up as amp;param2. I would like the paramter to be param2.

Comment: Why are you then escaping `&` to `&amp;`?

Comment: I'm trying to add support for both characters.